# Реализация собственного контейнера vector

Tags: c++, vector

Собственного говоря на просторах гугла есть множество примеров, но они все либо слишком простые, либо код прямо из стл(который для меня нечитабелен).
Мне интересна реализация вектора с реализацией собственного аллокатора,у кого-нибудь есть ссылки, или может быть заготовки?

Answer (score 1):

Есть много чего [тут](https://tproger.ru/category/translations/page/3/), в частности [тут](https://tproger.ru/translations/array-list-for-beginners/)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/109144)

Comment: @Streletz, впредь буду знать, спасибо

Comment: или, например, по ссылке можно получить `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`